# DataGridView cell validation takes two between rows

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a problem when trying to sum certain cells from a row. It takes too long when I click on a separate row after I enter a value. This doesn't happen when I click on another cell in the same row.

This is my code in the `CellValidated` event.

```
if (!_comparare)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText.Contains("COM"))
    {
        int total = 0;
        foreach (Gestiune gest in _selectedGestiuni)
        {
            int n = 0;
            total += Convert.ToInt32(int.TryParse(dataGridView1["COM_" + gest.Den_Gest, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(), out n) ? dataGridView1["COM_" + gest.Den_Gest, e.RowIndex].Value : 0);
        }
        dataGridView1["Total", e.RowIndex].Value = total;
    }
}
```

Please help me.
I don't understand why it doesn't work as fast as when going trough the cells of the same row.

Answer (score 0):

try to change your code from

```
dataGridView1["COM_" + gest.Den_Gest, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()
```

to

```
dataGridView1["COM_" + gest.Den_Gest, e.RowIndex].EditedValue.ToString()
```